# Is there any GUI VPN that I can use for 14.04?

Tags: vpn, gui

Can any one link me with a vpn software I can use with GUI not with terminal or manual stuff ?

Comment: Cisco Any Connect works with Linux and has a gui BUT(!) the VPN you need mostly depends on the other side supporting it. What is the use case?

Comment: Blocked ipv6 by my operator

Comment: VPN lets you route IPv6 over IPv4?

Comment: nope it's like blocked access for specific sites

Answer (score 0):

I use OpenConnect, once connected I open Remmina for the GUI connection.